# Element with display:none is not counted as hidden by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an element which has display:none initially. When I click a button, a jQuery event is triggered, and my script toggles the element's display attribute between block and none when the button is clicked.

I am trying to make it so the background of the element's parent changes color depending on whether or not the element is hidden.

```
$("#button").on('click', function(){
                if($(".hidden-content").is(":hidden")) {
                    $(".other-element").css("background-color","rgba(20,20,20,.9)");
                } else {
                    $(".other-element").css("background-color","rgba(20,20,20,0)");
                }
        })
```

For some reason, when I click the button to toggle the dropdown, the jQuery treats the .hidden-content like it's not hidden, even though when I inspect the element, it says 
    .other-element { display: none };

Does anyone know why this could be? Since the hiddenness is toggled using jQuery, it may not actually change .hidden-content's own css, but I don't see why that should be a problem on the very first click.

Comment: `.other-element` may have `{ display: none };`, but what about `.hidden-content`, which you're actually testing against? Edit: actually nevermind, you said `.other-element` is a parent so that `.hidden-content` should theoretically be considered hidden also.

Comment: I suggest you toggle classes instead of doing that what you're doing. You could make a class called hidden whose display property is set to hidden and some other class whose display property is set to block, inline or something else, and toggle the classes when the button is clicked and then test if the element has either the "hidden" class or the other class and set it's background accordingly. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to add a CSS class to the element whose `background-color` property you want to change. Check it out:

In your click function, you can use jQuery's `.toggleClass()` method to add and remove a CSS class every time the button is clicked. In your CSS, you can then override the default background color with the new class selector. There's an example below. It sounds like you have your own method of hiding and showing the content, so for this example I'm just going to use jQuery's `.toggle()` function to do that bit.

I've created a [working example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GQpaye) for you as well :)

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {

    // The important part: add and remove the CSS class to change colors!
    $('#parent-element').toggleClass('content-on');

    // Hide and show the content element. You can do this differently of course:
    $('.content').toggle();

});
```

And your CSS would look something like this:

```
#parent-element {
    background-color: rgba(20,20,20,.9);
}

#parent-element.content-on {
    background-color: rgba(20,20,20,0);
}
```

Comment: fixed it just by popping a $(".other-element").toggleClass("colored"); into jquery method i had already put on the button. I have no idea why this took me so long. Thanks!